# How does the Hide from Undead spell interact with the effect of an Invisibility Purge spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, undead, invisibility

Take a group of adventurers trying to get the drop on a lich or any other intelligent undead. They decide to use the spell [*hide from undead*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hide-from-undead/) to get into position. What they don't know is that the undead is cautious and has something producing an [*invisibility purge*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility-purge/) effect, like a [*lantern of revealing*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/lantern-of-revealing/).

The *hide from undead* spell description says:

> Undead cannot see, hear, or smell creatures warded by this spell.

But it's not listed as being invisible, and the [*invisibility*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility/) spell's school is actually illusion (glamer) whereas *hide from undead*'s is abjuration.

Would *hide from undead* keep the adventurers from being seen? Or would the *invisibility purge* effect make them visible?

Answer (score 4):

As written, *invisibility purge* does nothing against *hide from undead*. Nothing in *hide from undead* says anything about invisibility (and, indeed, its protections cover far more than invisibility does), and nothing in *invisibility purge* says anything about non-invisibility forms of hiding. Subjects of *hide from undead* may appear **as if** invisible to undead eyes, but that is not, apparently, how the spell works “under the hood” so to speak.

I could see houseruling things to give the undead more options against *hide from undead* if it was becoming a problem in a campaign, including perhaps expanding *invisibility purge*’s scope to cover it, but that would be a houserule and not one I’d bother with in most campaigns.

Comment: The easiest houserule to handle Hide from Undead in a problem situation might be a divination spell at the same level ("Reveal Living"?). That avoids messing with mechanics as much as possible, and is an interesting "niche" spell to add to your world's lore. Alternatively, consider a "Hide from Living" spell that's only usable by undead and let the players tell you how to solve the problem they created.